# Inline block size / horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <img src="" style="width:25px;" />
        <a href="" style="white-space:normal; display:inline-block;">a b c d ...</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In each item I have an image and an a tag. Unfortunately a can not remove the image, and displaying the a tag as an inline-block also can not be changed (the style of the li tag also not).

The problem: my texts in the a tag are quite long, multiline display is a must (white-space:normal), but somehow the width of the a tag is always wider than the container div :( Unofortunately I didn't find a way to remove the horizontal scrollbar.

The extra width is always equal to width of the the image. If a remove the image the scrollbar disappears.

Is it possible to do that without removing the image? The a tag should fill only the available space, but it is filling the space as if the image wouldn't be there.

https://jsfiddle.net/8aqoj3u0/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure the text is completely visible and wraps around the image try using `calc`.

Calc is really useful because it allows you to mix measurements. In this case the link width is set to 100% **minus** 25 pixels (to accommodate for your image).

so the code for this would be:

```css
a {
  white-space:normal; 
  display:inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 25px); /*Subtract 25px - the width of your image */
}
```

I've updated your plunker here: https://jsfiddle.net/1v1oeLtw/

Here's the browser support for it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 0):

To remove the horizontal scroll bar set the `overflow-x` property to hidden.

```
ul{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: That removes the scrollbar, but also hides the last 25 px of my text.

https://jsfiddle.net/8aqoj3u0/2/